# How to get current time video in <iframe> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get current time video from  tag html using javascript, but when I run the function to get it, I got an undefined pop up error.

This is my code :

```js
var x = document.querySelector("myVideo");

function getCurTime() {
  alert(x.currentTime);
}

function setCurTime() {
  x.currentTime = 5;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="myVideo" src='https://videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/a49ddab31116e7c52c/93b278e6bfc6cd4c' width='630' height='263' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>
           </iframe><br>
<button onclick="getCurTime()" type="button">Get current time position</button>
<button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button">Set time position to 5 seconds</button>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: `iframe` has no `currentTime` property. Only a `video` tag.

Comment: You can use the API to deal with the player. https://sproutvideo.com/help/articles/27-javascript_player_api

Comment: Your `<video>` tag is in an iframe and very likely to be inaccessible as a result of cross-domain scripting protections - unless your main page is also on the domain `sproutvideo.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `video` instead of `iframe`

```
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src='https://videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/a49ddab31116e7c52c/93b278e6bfc6cd4c' width='630' height='263' frameborder='0'" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Also, the query selector you used is incorrect:

```
// Change:
var x = document.querySelector("myVideo");

// To:
const videoQuerriedById = document.querySelector("#myVideo");
```